# Flathub packages are freezing system after upgrade to 19.10

Tags: 19.10, amdgpu, mesa, flatpak

Since I upgraded to 19.10 my system is freezing when starting Flatpak progs, like `Foliate` or `Visual Studio Code`. Can only hard shutdown.

Syslog shows error messages in Kernel amdgpu.

It seems this is a kernel/mesa bug that shows up on AMD GPU machines that have Mesa 19.2 and flatpak apps that use an older Mesa version.

How to solve that? Should I try to downgrade Mesa or somehow build the flatpak packages myself.

[Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1852865)

**UPDATE:**

Related issue:
[Mesa 19.2 doesn’t like Mesa inside 18.08 sandbox](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/some-flatpaks-kill-the-machine-on-f31sb-beta-testing/7673/4)

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

Use the snap version:

```
flatpak uninstall foliate
snap install foliate
```

`Foliate` working fine again.